# How do I .replace/remove within labelling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, python-parser

I would like to remove N_A and N123#N123 from my Labels. How do I do that?

So far:

```
str([RTN]).replace('N_A',' ')
```

I still Need to remove the eg. N123#N123 as well from the Labels, but keeping the single eg. N123 Labels.

Attribut Tabel:
N_A        to be removed
N123#N123  to be removed
N123       must not be removed
N321       must not be removed

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you want. Can 123 in N123 be any number with three digits? If not try:

Expression:

```
def FindLabel ( [Label]  ):
  a = [Label]
  a = a.replace('N_A','')
  if a.count('N123')>1:
    a = a.replace('N123','')
  return a
```

Change `Label` to match the name of your field

[image]

If it can be N+any three digits:

```
def FindLabel ( [Label]  ):
  import re
  p = re.compile("[N]\d{3}")
  a = [Label]
  a = a.replace('N_A','')
  if len(re.findall(p,a))>1:
    a = re.sub(p,'',a)
  return a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace any instance of *N_A* and *N123#N123*

you may use this label expression using the python parser option::

```
[RTN].replace('N_A','').replace('N123#N123','')
```